# Postgresql does not restart after changing max_connections or shared_buffers

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have tested pgtune on my postgres.config so I know what I can change there, but when I try to change max_connections or shared_buffers I can't restart postgres. I just get an error, but there is nothing in the log specifying the error. (Not sure where those logs go, but they are not in regular pg_log dir.)

My settings is:

```
shared_buffers = 24MB  # (pgtune wizard 2013-04-11 = 120MB)
max_connections = 120  # (pgtune wizard 2013-04-11 = 200)
```

Im on a 512 linode which only runs postgresql. If I change shared_buffers beyond 24MB or max_connections beyond 120, I can't restart postgres.

I'm running on a Linode xen instance with Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS:

```
Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.4-x86_64-linode31 x86_64)
```

Anyone know if postgres it self determine that 24MB and 120 connections is max for my system?

Comment: What operating system are you on?

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.8.4-x86_64-linode31 x86_64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're probably exceeding a very low default limit for shared memory.

This is covered in the manual - see [operating system resource limits](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/kernel-resources.html). For Linux, see `kernel.shmmax`.

On a side-note, increasing `max_connections` is often the wrong answer. Most PostgreSQL instances will work best with a relatively small number of actively working connections. It's often best to use *connection pooling* to queue up work; you'll get better overall throughput with lower resource use. If your application doesn't have a connection pool built-in you can use PgBouncer as an external connection pool.

Comment: Just skimmed through the documentation, but if I got the gist of it, I need to change my server settings?

Comment: @Garreth00 Assuming that my *guess* as to what is causing PostgreSQL to start is correct, yes. You'll need to check your logs for more info; it might be in `daemon.log` if it isn't in the PostgreSQL logs themselves. How are you stopping/starting PostgreSQL, anyway?

Comment: I agree with @CraigRinger. My experience is that VMs (linode is a VM?) and shared memory don't mix very well. Probably shared mem is *pinned* into physical memory somehow, and the VM is tight on resources. IMHO you should increse estimated_cache_size instead, and keep shared mem to the bare minimum (caching catalogs, storing session data+semafores, etc).

Comment: @wildplasser That hasn't been my experience; I've had no issues bumping shm up on Xen VMs like Amazon EC2 and Linode, you just have to increase `kernel.shmmax` like any other Linux host.

Comment: @CraigRinger: I got the feeling that the OP does not have total control over the kernel shm settings. Not sure about the shm being pinned, though (that would make instance swapping a very costly process) I agree with you about the max_connections; combinatorial explosion is lurking in the dark, somewhere. *l'enfer, c'est les autres ... and all that stuff*

Comment: @wildplasser If they're on linode, as they appear to be, then they do have control over kernel shm. Linode also supports booting a custom Xen Linux kernel via pvgrub if you don't want to use their canned kernels. The Xen host doesn't care what the underlying instance does with its RAM, pinned or otherwise, so that shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @CraigRinger: Thank you! Do you recommend pgbouncer on my my db-server or my django/app server?

Comment: @Garreth00 Doesn't make much difference, whatever's convenient.